# when trying to use ms-clear on element it doesnt work

Tags: css

I have a button

```
<button class="close"></button>
```

With this css

```
button.close {
    font-size: 14px;
}

button.close::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

But i cant make the ms clear work. What is wrong?

Comment: `-ms-clear` is for creating a clear button on a text input only, and only works in IE 10, 11 and edge. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-ms-clear` can only be applied on an input with type text. It is non-standard and only works in IE 10, 11 and Edge.

This pseudo-element is used to modify a little button which is visible by default to clear input boxes. You can see it working [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxRqzm), if you have an edge browser. Just click into the textbox and write something and a little cross will appear on the right side of the input box.

Comment: Exactly the thing i want to achieve is that in edge that stupid cross will disappear =) i want to use default styling not the one IE adds to it

Comment: so you were on the right track!  you just need to use it on the input instead of a button and you are done =)

Answer (score 1):

from the [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear)

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.